# Security of JWT token and AzureB2C

Tags: c#, security, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have a .net Core API and Next.JS frontend (with MSAL). I use Azure AdB2C for authenticating users. Currently I'm thinking about storing the roles of the user and the organization Id / Tenant Id for the user in B2C and return it in the token. Is this considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You wouldn't have to store the tenantID. You can derive it from:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
```

It's returned by default in the SUSI policies in the starter pack.

Roles are just claims; storing and returning them in the JWT is normal.